# Reverse Google Image Search

Tags: android, web, reddit, google-image-search

I'm trying to reverse image search a url from an android app. The base url I'm using is:

```
https://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=
```

This works for most urls, however certain ones don't working from the app, for example with the url from a reddit post:

`https://i.reddituploads.com/bb7b0423593e413f88126a3a970dfb1a?fit=max&h=1536&w=1536&s=a057607161cdbab59d30ee2c6f0d88f0`

which becomes

```
https://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://i.reddituploads.com/bb7b0423593e413f88126a3a970dfb1a?fit=max&h=1536&w=1536&s=a057607161cdbab59d30ee2c6f0d88f0
```

But that says "The URL doesn't refer to an image, or the image not publicly accessible." However if I go to images.google.com and paste `https://i.reddituploads.com/bb7b0423593e413f88126a3a970dfb1a?fit=max&h=1536&w=1536&s=a057607161cdbab59d30ee2c6f0d88f0` manually it works perfectly fine. Any ideas why it would be having an issue with some urls and not others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode the URL first to something like:

https://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https%3A//i.reddituploads.com/bb7b0423593e413f88126a3a970dfb1a%3Ffit%3Dmax%26h%3D1536%26w%3D1536%26s%3Da057607161cdbab59d30ee2c6f0d88f0

I am familiar with java, but python has a function to encode the URL to the desired form: [`urllib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote)